# How calculate mean and median of dictionary data in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am appeding dictinary values but how calculate median of this data? I have another method for calculate mean that works but median occurs error...

```
arr = []
for i in range(n):
     data =  getValues() #[{450: 37, 451: 59, 452: 18, 453: 88, 454: 52},{450: 40, 451: 27, 452: 26, 453: 15, 454: 20},{450: 16, 451: 12, 452: 12, 453: 13, 454: 13},{450: 7, 451: 5, 452: 6, 453: 5, 454: 5}]
     od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))
     arr.append(od )

medianArr = np.median(arr, axis=0)
meanArr = np.mean(arr)
np.savetxt("dataMedian.txt", medianArr , fmt="%s", delimiter=",")   #only values, without keys
np.savetxt("dataMean.txt", meanArr , fmt="%s", delimiter=",")  #only values, without keys
```

my working method for mean:

```
arr2d = []
for i in range(n):
    count += 1
    data =  getValues() #[{450: 37, 451: 59, 452: 18, 453: 88, 454: 52},{450: 40, 451: 27, 452: 26, 453: 15, 454: 20},{450: 16, 451: 12, 4652: 12, 453: 13, 454: 13},{450: 7, 451: 5, 452: 6, 453: 5, 454: 5}]
    od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))
    arr = []
    for k, v in od.items():
        arr.append(v/count)
    arr2d.append(arr)

np.savetxt("dataMean.txt", arr2d, fmt="%s", delimiter=",") #ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work with NumPy utilities, you can stack your dictionaries' values in a single array:

```
>>> arr = np.stack([list(d.values()) for d in data])
array([[37, 59, 18, 88, 52],
       [40, 27, 26, 15, 20],
       [16, 12, 12, 13, 13],
       [ 7,  5,  6,  5,  5]])
```

Then, assuming you're looking to compute the statistics of your data per dictionary, you can do:

```
>>> np.mean(arr, 1), np.median(arr, 1)
(array([50.8, 25.6, 13.2,  5.6]), array([52., 26., 13.,  5.]))
```

You can of course compute the global mean and median by removing the axis option on both calls.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: Make sure you've defined `data` as your list of *dict*s, *i.e.* `[{450: 37, 451: 59, 452: 18, 453: 88, 454: 52},{450: 40, 451: 27, 452: 26, 453: 15, 454: 20},{450: 16, 451: 12, 4652: 12, 453: 13, 454: 13},{450: 7, 451: 5, 452: 6, 453: 5, 454: 5}]`

Comment: the date is larger and I am using the order method above `od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))`... see [here](https://ctxt.io/2/AACgB5-uFw)

Comment: What is your input data, you said `getValues()` was returning a list of *dict*s, correct? If you're computing the mean and median with NumPy you don't need to sort your data beforehand... That's why I gave this solution in my answer.

Comment: ok, but If I use your solution, still same error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: If you use the provided lines above on `data`, defined as a *list* of *dict*s, then it **will** work. Are you using something else as `data`?

Comment: Well I'm sorry you must be wrong, if you do `data = [{450: 37, 451: 59, 452: 18, 453: 88, 454: 52},{450: 40, 451: 27, 452: 26, 453: 15, 454: 20},{450: 16, 451: 12, 4652: 12, 453: 13, 454: 13},{450: 7, 451: 5, 452: 6, 453: 5, 454: 5}]`, and `arr = np.stack([list(d.values()) for d in data])`, then `np.mean(arr, 1), np.median(arr, 1)` will give you the desired result.

Comment: thank you, a create another solution adapting my old code for means and using part of your code -> just changing with axis =0:  `np.median(arr, 0)`